# Operation based on names in Julia NamedArray()

Tags: arrays, julia, named

I want to apply a conditional function on a NamedArray in Julia and the condition is based on the row/column names. I have problem with applying the condition on names. For example, consider

```
A = NamedArray([1, 2, 3, 4], (["Aa", "Ab", "Ba", "Bb"]))
```

and I want to multiply elements by 2 if the second letter is "a". The below code does not work:

```
(1 .+ SubString.(names(A), 2, 2) .== "a") .* A
```

and the `SubString()` gives error

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching SubString(::Vector{String}, ::Int64, ::Int64)
```

Comment: `A .* (1 .+ (getindex.(names(A,1), 2) .== 'a'))` may be what is needed here.

Comment: It works, thanks! The problem was `names(A)` instead of `names(A, 1)` and `A` come before `.*` not after it.

Comment: If you add the answer as an answer. This question can be resolved (and won't attract undue attention).

Comment: @DanGetz, I did that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @DanGetz 's comment, this works:

```
A .* (1 .+ (getindex.(names(A,1), 2) .== 'a'))
```

or this one with SubString():

```
A .* (1 .+ (SubString.(names(A,1), 2) .== "a"))
```